# Github actions and google cloud storage credentials python

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, credentials, github-actions

I want to process a csv using a python script in github actions.

This csv is stored in GCP.

So I want to upload and download the files from google storage using the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
class gcpConection(object,st):

    def __init__(self):

        self.credentials_path = 'credentials.json'
        self.bucket_name = 'name'

    def download_and_read_files(filename):
        st = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(self.credentials_path)
        bucket = st.get_bucket(self.bucket_name)
        blob_csv = bucket.get_blob(filename)
        blob_csv.download_to_filename(filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        return df
    def upload_files(folder,filename):
        st = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(self.credentials_path)
        bucket = st.get_bucket(self.bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob('{}/{}'.format(folder,filename))
        blob.upload_from_filename(filename)
```

This code is runing perfectly in my computer, the credentials.json is stored in the same folder as the script.

To run it in Github actions I can't upload this json file, so I thought to store this json as a secret in github secrets.

I know that this secret is stored here `secrents.gcp_credential` but I don't kow then how to change the code in the script to tell to google cloud storage to look the credentials there, something like this:

```
self.credentials_path = path/secrents.gcp_credential
```

I don't if it is the correct way to do it. Also I have an access key and a secret, but I don't know how it works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: ["Creating and storing encrypted `secrets`"](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets):

> `Secrets` are encrypted environment variables that you create in a repository for use with GitHub Actions...
>   To make a secret available to an action, you must set the secret as an input or environment variable in the workflow file.

There you can fing [how to create the encrypted `secrets`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets):

> To provide an action with a secret as an input or environment variable, you can use the secrets context to access secrets you've created in your repository. For more information, see "Context and expression syntax for GitHub Actions" and "Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions."

```
steps:
  - name: Hello world action
    with: # Set the secret as an input
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    env: # Or as an environment variable
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
```

Just keep in mind that there are some limitations for `secrets`, such as you can have up to 100 secrests, the na,es must be unique in a repository, they are limited to 64 KB in size.